# Terminal doesn't show the activated environment properly

Tags: linux, conda

I got a problem about terminal environment problem.

For example, I got two environments, base and test1. When I activate the test1 environment running

```
conda activate test1
```

the environment shown in the terminal will still be

```
(base)user:
```

It doesn't properly show the currently running environment. Anybody knows how to fix it?

Before this bug, I tried to set the default environment to be test1 and used the command line `conda config --set env_prompt '(test1)'`, does it has something to do with the bug?

Comment: Can you check that after you use `conda activate test1`, dose the env gets activated or not? You can check with `conda env list` command. Current env will have * after name.

Comment: Moved my comment to an answer since that appears to have fixed things. In the future, please do not answer in the question body. Better etiquette would have been to ping me that my suggestion resolved things, and offer me the chance to make it an answer. Or, if you had figured out a different solution, post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is likely the command that was run to manipulate the `env_prompt` configuration is a factor. Also note that it definitely is not for setting a default environment.

To reset the configuration, please try running:

```bash
conda config --remove-key env_prompt
```